# Use results from one SQL query to form part of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries one of which relies on input from another:

Query #1:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM ISET.ACCOUNT
WHERE HOLDER='12345'
```

This will return a list of `ACCOUNT_ID` associated with holder `12345`

I then need to pass these `account IDs` to the following query to show a list of transactions associated with all the account ids picked up

```
SELECT TRANS_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, "REF"
FROM ISET.ENTRY
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID='LIST OF ACCOUNT IDS';
```

How would I find the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a subselect combined with the `IN` statement.

```
SELECT TRANS_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, "REF"
FROM ISET.ENTRY
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
                    FROM ISET.ACCOUNT
                    WHERE HOLDER='12345');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TRANS_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, 'REF'
  FROM ISET.ENTRY
 WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
                        FROM ISET.ACCOUNT
                       WHERE HOLDER='12345');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT TRANS_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, "REF"
FROM ISET.ENTRY
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
                     FROM ISET.ACCOUNT
                     WHERE HOLDER = '12345'
                    );
```